# Using multiple dataset in the same chart with different values

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-chartjs-2. I have a Line chart and x: time y: value. I have 2 different dataset. First dataset value is very as low as 0.00000145 and etc. The second dataset value is as high as millions. When i use this in the same chart, first dataset is at the bottom and looks like a single straight line as chart comparing 2 datasets. Time is same for both datasets. So what is the best way to see two different datasets self comparing?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way is to make single chart, which will show correlation between two datasets - the division of first dataset's values by another's. I think, it may be representative

Comment: Aren't there any way to do it using real data? Because that would come up with a wrong chart